# Matrix - vector multiplication with boundary conditions in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, data-analysis

I have been assigned to set up a matrix-vector multiplication with boundary conditions, to solve the wave equation using an iterative method. However, I am struggling to set up the question.

[Sparse matrix problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJsC8.png)

How would I go about implementing the boundary conditions? This is what I have so far:

```
def matrix_problem(N):
    """Generate the matrix and rhs associated with the wave equation."""

    k = (29 * np.pi) / 2
    h = 1 / N
    
    nelements = (2-((h**2)*(k**2))) -2

    row_ind = np.empty(nelements, dtype=np.float64)
    col_ind = np.empty(nelements, dtype=np.float64)
    data = np.empty(nelements, dtype=np.float64)

    f = np.empty(N * N, dtype=np.float64)

    count = 0
    for j in range(N):
        for i in range(N):
                if i==j:
                    row_ind[count] = 1
                    col_ind[count] = 1
                else:
                    if j==i:
                        row_ind[count] = 2-(h**2)*(k**2)
                        col_ind[count] = 2-(h**2)*(k**2)
                    if j==i+1 or j==i-1:
                        row_ind[count] = -1
                        col_ind[count] = -1
                    else:   
                        row_ind[count] = 0
                        col_ind[count] = 0
                    
    return coo_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), shape(N**2, N**2)).tocsr(), f
```

I have tried to set up the matrix-vector problem but I have implemented the boundary conditions incorrectly. I am new to coding so I don't really understand what I am doing or why, or how it could be wrong. I have tried implementing the `if` parts differently but I am running into the same issue which is that no matrix is being created.

```
N = 100

A, f = discretise_poisson(N)
sol = spsolve(A, f)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/d4/xpz4321n1k927dx91d1ntp6w0000gn/T/ipykernel_71373/3717722815.py in <module>
      1 N = 100
      2 
----> 3 A, f = matrix_problem(N)
      4 sol = spsolve(A, f)
      5 

/var/folders/d4/xpz4321n1k927dx91d1ntp6w0000gn/T/ipykernel_71373/3681280231.py in matrix_problem(N)
      7     nelements = (2-((h**2)*(k**2))) -2
      8 
----> 9     row_ind = np.empty(nelements)
     10     col_ind = np.empty(nelements)
     11     data = np.empty(nelements)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Unfortunately I do not know what I am doing and all that code there is purely guesswork. I have asked my lecturer for help but of course no reply from them, so I have to ask here instead. An example would be great so I can understand how it is set up, so I can actually crack on with the assignment (which is speeding up the iterative solver using GPU acceleration).

Comment: Your code example and the error output do not correspond to each other.  In the code example you have `N = 200`, but your error message shows that you have `N = 100.0`, which is a float (i.e. floating point number) and not an integer.  Do you actually get the same error when you use `N = 200`?  Or `N = 100` for that matter.

Comment: Yeah mate sorry for the discrepancy I will fix that now. For any values of N though, the code doesn't work, I tried 3 values of N which the question states, for N=10, 100 and 1000

Comment: Right, but what about the type? If you run `print(type(N))`, what does that return?

Comment: I see that the numbers now match, but the traceback still appears to indicate that you are using `N = 100.0` and not `N = 100`.  You need to make sure you do not have the decimal point in your script.

Comment: @NickODell ```print(type(N))``` returns ```<class 'int'>```

Comment: @Malcolm I tried removing the decimal point and still returning the same error. I am thinking the problem is the way I have interpreted the question :/

Comment: Try adding `N = int(N)` to the top of your matrix_problem method.  Also there appear to be what I was assuming were cut-and-paste errors in your matrix_problem code: the indentation of the `f = np...` and `return ...` lines appears off.

Comment: Yeah mate, the same error occurs if I try ```N=int(N)```. I will fix the indent errors from the copy and paste from vscode, I'll just fix now so we don't get confused.

Comment: Duh.  It is the calculation of `nelements` that is causing the problem.  `k` is a floating point number.  You need to convert that to an integer so that `nelements` is an integer.  Sorry to have been distracted by the floating point `N` in the traceback.

Comment: ```k``` is given as ```29 \pi / 2``` so I am not sure how that would work. Surely the decimal points are needed for accuracy sake

Comment: Why do you need floating point accuracy to determine how many nonzero elements there should be in the sparse matrix?  That number must be a positive integer.

Comment: Make `data`, `row_ind`, `col_ind` [] lists, and append the values in the i,j loop.  That way you don't have make some wild guess at `nelements`.  Using `np.empty` is not wise unless you **know** you'll assign every element.

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot to learn about programming, `python`, `numpy`, `scipy.sparse`.   But one of first things is learning to debug.

I never write code just from an editor.  I always have an interactive python session at hand where I can test pieces of code.

Let's test your `nelement` calculation lines:

```
In [229]: N=100; k = (29 * np.pi) / 2
     ...: h = 1 / N
     ...: nelements = (2-((h**2)*(k**2))) -2

In [230]: N,h,k,nelements
Out[230]: (100, 0.01, 45.553093477052, -0.20750843253290374)
```

So even with `N=100` an integer, `h=1/100` is a float.  `k` is bigger, but `nelements` is still a float, and not just a float, is small `0.2`.  You can't define a array with a float, much less on less than 1.  Worse yet, it's negative!

I don't know where you are getting these calculations from, but clearly they are wrong.

I suspect you have copy-n-pasted code from some source, without any idea of what's going on.  Doing that will leave you will lots of debugging problems.